# python return from function

Tags: python, function, cpython

Is it possible to return from a function and continue executing code from just under the function. I know that may sound vague but here is an example:

---

```py
def sayhi():
    print("hi")
    continue_function() #makes this function continue below in stead of return

#the code continues here with execution and will print hey
print("hey")


sayhi()
```

---

when executing this the code should do this:

- it prints "hey"
- it calls the sayhi() function
- it prints "hi"
- it calls a function to make it continue after the function (in theory similar behavour could be achieve by using decorators)
- it prints "hey" again
- it calls sayhi() again
- etc

---

i am fully aware of the fact that similar behaviour can be achieved by just using for loops but for the project i am working on this functionality is *required* and not achievable by using looping.

---

some solutions i have thought of (but i have no clue how i could execute them) are:

- somehow clearing the stack python uses to return from one function to another
- changing return values
- changing python itself (just to make clear: it would solve the problem but it is something i do *not* want to do beacuse the project must be usable on non-altered versions of python
- using some c extension to change python's behaviour from within python itself

Comment: No, Python has no 'goto' functionality.

Comment: This would also completely break Python's frame stack model.

Comment: i know it hasn't, but is there some workaround but it's just not intended to be used, or is it absolutely impossible?

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: Not that you have shared your use-case or why you think it is required for your project, this sounds like a [massive X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: alrighty, then thanks for the help and i'll just accept it's (unfortunately) impossible

Answer (score 1):

Repetition without loops can be done with recursion:

```
def sayhi():
    print("hey")
    print("hi")
    sayhi()


sayhi()
```

I assume you have some terminating condition to insert. If not, this code will give a `RecursionError`.

Comment: of course that works. thanks for your help. it is however not what i'm looking for. i specifically want it to execute the code after the function so loops nor recursion will work. but thanks anyways.